# How do I make my pull request only show the changes since my last pull request on github?

Tags: github, request, pull

How do I go about making my pull requests have only the changes made on the new branch? Every time I push a branch it has all the changes from the previous branches included in the pull request also.

My manager is really big on making sure we do small PRs and have only the new changes on each one for easy review, but I'm at a complete loss as to how to do this. This is my first dev job and up until now I unfortunately haven't been able to do group work so managing PRs that might be a while before they are merged in is totally new to me.

So far I've only found how to cherry pick commits, is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have a main branch (`master`?) that contains the latest version of your software and you have one or more other branches that contain modifications. You do some more modifications in that other branch and if you create a pull request it will contain all other changes.

The most simple solution I can think of is to use dedicated branches for all changes. Before starting to work, create a new branch from the main branch with the ticket ID, work description or whatever you use to describe your work: `git branch -b feature-123`.
Commit to this branch only and push it to the repo. If you now create a pull request from this feature branch to the main branch, it will only contain the changes you did and nothing else.

The further pull requests highly depend on your internal workflow and branch structure. But basically this workflow applies to all new changes.

Comment: I see where I wasn't clear. We are suppose to make a branch, get to a reasonable stopping point and make a pull request, then continue on on a mew branch rather than continuing to commit to the same one while we wait for the pull request to be reviewed (issue15-pt1, issue15-pt2, etc...) But we are suppose to make each pull request to only have the newest set of changes not all the changes in the chain waiting to be merged across all the parts branchs.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just tested this with a plain repo and I couldn't find a way to do this in a clean and easy way. Neither rebasing nor merging worked correctly without using a force push or getting merge commits.